# Need advice on using layer 2 in dex

Tags: solidity, hardhat, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3, layer-2

I have created a Dex, I want to use its swap and providing liquidity functionality through layer 2, how to do that? If u answer with code example then it will be very helpful for me, I can understand it better then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have created the DEX yourself, only you can answer this question.

Nobody else knows what kind of DEX you have created and why.

[Please also see xyproblem.info](https://xyproblem.info/)